# Relational database engine for Swift developers

Tags: database

What choices do [Swift](https://developer.apple.com/swift/) developers have for a robust relational database engine embedded in their apps? Especially for [Cocoa](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocoa_(API)) native (Xcode) macOS or iOS apps?

By ‘robust’ I mean architected to prioritize preserving my data (versus performance or such), [ACID](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) compliant, strong support for date-time handling, savvy handling of concurrency, stable runtime without exaggerated crashing or memory usage or CPU hogging, and preferably native support for [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UUID) as a data type including as primary key.

[SQLite](https://sqlite.org/) is too lite.

[MySQL](https://www.mysql.com/) is not as robust or powerful as I would like.

[Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org) is robust and powerful, but not suitable for embedding.

[H2 Database Engine](http://h2database.com/) seems to be an excellent database but, being written in pure [Java](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(programming_language)), requires a [JVM](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) to be embedded as well. [Embedding a JVM is doable on macOS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/package_for_mac.html) but I don't know about iOS. Similar to H2 is [Apache Derby](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Derby) and [HSQLDB](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSQLDB). Not sure how to connect to any of these as there is no JDBC driver that can be called from a native Xcode app.

I wonder about [Firebird](http://www.firebirdsql.org/) 3, but I am unfamiliar.